# bash test with double brackets doesn't validate regex correctly

Tags: regex, bash

I'm new to the bash scripting world, and during learning I wrote a simple password validator script:

```
#! /bin/bash

args=("$@")
PASSWORD=${args[1]}
if [[ "$PASSWORD" =~ [0-9A-Za-z] ]]
then
    echo "PASSWORD LEGIT"
else
    echo "WRONG PASSWORD"
    fi
```

With the argument `PassWord12`, it should output `PASSWORD LEGIT`, yet it doesn't.
I'm using double brackets instead of 'test' syntax.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: You are testing that the password _contains_ a digit or letter, not that it is _composed of_ digits and letters. Is this your intention?

Comment: If the password should be not only one character long but be at least 8 characters long, then I would replace `[0-9A-Za-z]` with `[0-9A-Za-z]{8,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `declare -p args`, you will get `declare -a args=([0]="PassWord12")` which clearly indicates the value you passed has the 0<sup>th</sup> index in the array. Positional parameters start at `1`, but array indices start at `0`.

You may use

```sh
args=("$@")
PASSWORD="${args[0]}"
if [[ "$PASSWORD" =~ [0-9A-Za-z] ]]
then
    echo "PASSWORD LEGIT"
else
    echo "WRONG PASSWORD"
fi
```

If you `echo` the `$PASSWORD`, you will see you will see the value passed to the script.

Note that you probably want to use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of a `[0-9A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @יוני ארליך _Positional parameters_ start at 1 but _array indices_ start at 0.

Comment: `declare -p args` is a handy way to inspect an array.